# Delphi - How to get dataset's OldValue and NewValue for blob field as streams

Tags: delphi, blob, firebird, delphi-xe

On Delphi XE I'm using [OldValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.OldValue) and [NewValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.NewValue) from TpFIBDataSet (but it can be applied to any TDataSet descendant) in order to verify if different fields have changed. My question is how can I retrieve these 2 values for blob fields as TMemoryStreams? I've made some research, but I found nothing.

Comment: I know of no way to do it with the native code.  Have you thought about implementing your own sub-class that mimics the behavior of the old and new values, but returns `TBytes` instead of `Variant`?

Comment: I was thinking on that too. My problem is that I can not have both old stream and the new one. Let's say that in that binary stream you have an RTF file, or an image file. How can you verify the new one against the old one, without making a supplementary query?

Comment: I think I found a way to detect whether a BLOB has changed, since you can't use `OldValue` and `NewValue` for BLOBs.  I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I've modified the question in order to reflect what I want - how to get OldValue and NewValue properties of a blob field as streams, without making a supplementary query.

Comment: What does it matter what the old and new values are if all you're trying to do is detect when the BLOB is modified? Just use the `.Modified` property.

Comment: If you need the old and new values for another reason, then you'll have to sub-class the dataset component and write new code to return BLOBs as bytes instead of as Variant, or store the before in a memory stream before the user edits it so you have the before and after, or clone (or copy) the dataset so you have a copy of the old values before the user changes them. I might be able to provide more info if you explain how you intend to use the old and new streams.

Comment: I agree with the above comment by @James. The only reason I can think of to actually have the 2 values, is if you write some kind of history log to the DB, and want to store the before and after data.

Comment: Yes, indeed. @JamesL. - I need the old value and new value for the blob fields as memorystreams.So probably I will store the value before the editing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a routine to detect if a field changed so I can limit the fields I send to the database to only the ones that changed.  I added code to that routine today to handle BLOB fields, since they cannot be returned `.AsVariant`, which is how `OldValue` and `NewValue` are returned.  I have not tested this with all of my use cases, but so far it seems pretty solid.

```
function FieldChanged(DataSet: TDataSet; FieldName: string): Boolean;
var
  fld: TField;
begin
  fld := DataSet.FieldByName(FieldName);

  if fld.IsBlob then
    Exit((fld as TBlobField).Modified);

  if (fld.OldValue = Null) and (fld.NewValue = Unassigned) then // This happens when a NULL field does not change
    Exit(False)
  else
    Exit(fld.OldValue <> fld.NewValue);
end;
```

Comment: If `fld` is of type `nvarchar(max)` or `xml`, it also evaluates as a BLOB, which works well for detecting a modified values.

Comment: +1 I didn't even realized that a TBlobField had a Modified property.

Comment: ok. So this is showing only if a blob field has been changed.

Comment: That's they way that I understand it.  If the BLOB field changed, `Modified` is *true*, otherwise it is *false*.  So you can't tell how it was modified, but at least you know **if** it changed, which is what I understood you wanted to know [**in order to verify if different fields have changed**].

Comment: I know the Modified property, and how it is working. I asked how can I retrieve the old and the new value of the field. "My question is how can I retrieve these 2 values for the blob fields as TMemoryStream". Thank you for the effort, the answer will help others to see if a blob field was modified.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
var
  stream: TBytesStream;
begin
  if not DataSet.FieldByName('blobfield').IsNull then
  begin
    stream := TBytesStream.Create(DataSet.FieldByName('blobfield').AsBytes);
    // do something with the stream
    FreeAndNil(stream);
  end;
end;
```

I prefer using `TBytesStream` because it accomplishes the same things I typically use a `TMemoryStream` for, and if you look at its constructor, it doesn't reallocate memory and copy the binary data to it like `TMemoryStream` does.

If you really need to use `TMemoryStream`, you could easily save the `TBytesStream` to the `TMemoryStream` using the `TBytesStream.SaveToStream()` method.